# How to redirect a site to the Facebook canvas URL without going to an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

If my Facebook canvas page is pointing to mydomain.com, and if a user goes directly to mydomain.com, how do I make the site show up on the Facebook canvas page?  Basically, I want my website to always load on the Facebook canvas.  If I just do a redirect to apps.facebook.com/mydomain, I think it gets into an infinite loop because the Facebook canvas is trying to load mydomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the referrer in the HTTP request header, and base your logic on that. That being said, I don't know that redirecting your entire site to Facebook is a good solution to your problem.

A better solution would be to host the Facebook app portions on a separate page or domain, and link to it from your frontpage.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it client side in javascript. Check if the page is currently opened inside an iframe, if it's not the case you are not inside facebook and should execute a redirect:

if(window.parent === window) do the redirect

You could find a way to implement it serverside, but, unless facebook is passing some specific parameters when loading, probably you will need to rely on the HTTP_REFERER parameter and the browsers will not send it always.

Comment: Thanks, tried this and this method works.  Only thing though is that after the redirect, my google fonts css is not getting loaded (other local stylesheets seem to get loaded).

Comment: check if they are working in a version of the same page non included inside facebook

Answer (score 1):

If your app is being loaded within Facebook, the page will be POSTed to, and the POST data will contain a `signed_request` field. This can be used on the server to discover if the user is accessing the app correctly - how you persist this information across navigation within the iframe is up to you.

Client side you can check `window !== top`, and `/canvas/.test(window.name)`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on another question and use it in my own script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function NotInFacebookFrame() {
    return top === self;
  }
  function ReferrerIsFacebookApp() {
    if(document.referrer) {
      return document.referrer.indexOf("apps.facebook.com") != -1;
    }
    return false;
  }
  if (NotInFacebookFrame()) {
    top.location.replace("https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE");
  }
</script>
```

This checks if they are currently in the Facebook frame and *ONLY if they are not it will redirect them to "https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE"

**Note:** you can use this on any page in you app just change the URL accordingly.

**For example:** If you are using this in http://YourDomain.com/anotherpage.php you can change the URL in the code above to https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE/anotherpage.php